# change of variables in an integral with arbitrary probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

My question (and I am not very familiar with the subject) is that if we have a simple integration, we can make the change of variables $x=z^2$ to get

$\int g(x) f(x) dx=\int 2z g(z^2)f(z^2)  dz.$

Now, what happens if I don't have a density function like $f(x)$ and have a probability measure $df$ instead? Is the following true?

$\int g(x) df(x)\overset{?}{=}\int g(z^2) df(z^2)$

If it is true, can I simplify $df(z^2)$ and relate it to $df(z)$?

Comment: So you need to be careful about making a non-invertible transformation like $x=z^2$, but if the invertibility issue is taken care of, then yes, this is admissible, and the measure $df(z^2)$ is called the pushforward measure.

Comment: @Ian, thanks for your answer, but is there a relation between $df(z^2)$ and $df(z)$?

Comment: In general there is not a simple way to represent $df(g(z))$ in terms of $df(z)$, except through the defining relationship. That is, in general you don't have a nice relationship along the lines of $df(g(z))=g'(z) df(z)$.